# SDWebimage to load image in custom UITableViewCell, but when scroll the image load in other cell random

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

i have insert in my uitableview with custom uitableviewcell the SDWebImage project, and i do this to load image:

```
[cell.img_cell setImageWithURL:[self.url objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
           placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:nil]
                  completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType) {...}];
```

but when i scroll the uitableview the image in one cell, goes in a cell that for example doens't have loaded yet the image, and continue this effect for all the cell that i scroll, and if i scroll up the tableview fast the cell that have loaded the right image first, then change it random like i said above, how i can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table cells are being reused as you scroll.  This means that when the image load finishes, the cell might not "belong" to the original URL anymore.

What you should do is set the image to `nil` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to clear out any reused images and then then cancel any pending requests in `tableView:didEndDisplayingCell:`, however this doesn't make efficient use of network bandwidth.

A better approach would be to move your image loading code into the table controller (using `SDWebImageManager`) and have it wait to look up the proper cell once the image has finished loading.